# Remove address bar shortcuts

Tags: firefox, windows-11, bookmarks

How can I get rid of these seemingly permanent bookmarks from the address bar in Firefox?

Firefox 121.0 (64-bit)
Win11 Home

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to go in `Settings` > `Search` > `Search Suggestions` > `Change settings for other address bar suggestions` > Uncheck `Shortcuts` and `Search engines`

Here an example :

[image]